# How do you call a custom field in a twig template in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, twig, custom-fields

I have a wordpress site using a twig template. I'm trying to call and display a custom field.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you tried `get_post_meta('post_id','custom_field', true);`  ?

Comment: My files are .twig so php codes are not working. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can call wpcf values easily with post.get_field().

Ex:

```
{{post.get_field('wpcf-ticket-url')}}
```

Also you may create any helper functions to extend your twig library. You can assign them on functions.php file in your twig theme folder.

Ex:

**twig-theme/functions.php:**

```
$context['get_custom_meta'] = TimberHelper::function_wrapper( 'get_custom_meta', array('',0) );//array contains default values

function get_custom_meta($key,$id){
    if(empty($id)){
       return types_render_field($key,  array("raw"=>"true","separator"=>";"));
    }else{
       return get_post_meta( $id, 'wpcf-'.$key, true );
    }
}
```

**twig-theme/views/xxx.twig :**

```
{{ get_custom_meta("ticket-url",item.object_id) }}
```